# How to calculate Bias and Variance to get the MSE value step by step?

Tags: r, variance, bias, mse, bias-variance-tradeoff

I want to compute my MSE value for a forecast step by step for  test set.

For me the Bias is:

Bias = mean(predicted values - actual values)

Variance = mean((predicted values- actual values)^2)

MSE = Bias^2 + Variance

When I compare my solution with the solution that i get from the R function MSE i get a wrong number. Do i miss something?

Comment: R might not be dividing by the sample size, maybe the sample size minus the number of parameters ($SSE/n$ vs $SSE/(n-p)$).

Answer (score 0):

$MSE(x_0)\space$ = $\space E_T \left[f(x_0) - \hat{y}_0 \right]^2$

$\quad\quad\quad\quad$ = $\space E_T \left[\hat{y}_0 - E_T(\hat{y}_0)\right]^2 +\left[E_T(\hat{y}_0) - f(x_0)\right]^2$

$\quad\quad\quad\quad$ = $\space Var_T(\hat{y}_0) + Bias^2(\hat{y}_0)$

I think this is what you are looking for. Did you try to square your bias term?